# Cannot deserialize the current JSON array (e.g. [1,2,3]). C#,

Tags: c#, json, blazor

I've been trying to deserialize a json file in my Blazor application using JSON.net. I know that the error is coming from my side, I've read many other problems on SO mentionning this error but I was not able to solve it, if anyone has a few seconds to take a look at it and tell me what I did wrong ? : Here is the json file :

```
[
  {
    "rows": [
      [
        "A",
        "Z",
        "E",
        "R",
        "T",
        "Y",
        "U",
        "I",
        "O",
        "P"
      ],
      [
        "Q",
        "S",
        "D",
        "F",
        "G",
        "H",
        "J",
        "K",
        "L",
        "M"
      ],
      [
        "MAJ",
        "w",
        "X",
        "C",
        "V",
        "B",
        "N",
        "'",
        "DELETE"
      ],
      [
        "123",
        ",",
        "SPACE",
        "."
      ]
    ]
  },
  {
    "rows": [
      [
        "1",
        "2",
        "3"
      ],
      [
        "4",
        "5",
        "6"
      ],
      [
        "7",
        "8",
        "9"
      ],
      [
        "ABC",
        ",",
        "SPACE",
        "."
      ]
    ]
  }
]
```

Here are the objects :

```
public class KeyBoardConfig
{
    public KeyBoardRowBase[] Rows { get; set; }
}
 public class KeyBoardRowBase
{
    public string[] characters { get; set; }
}
```

And the serialization :

```
string json = await Http.GetStringAsync("standard_keyboard.json");
var result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<KeyBoardConfig[]>(json);
```

Comment: What is the error message?

Comment: your C# code would work for json like `{ "rows" : [ {  "characters": [ "a", "b" ]}]}` and obviously not for that you provided

Comment: Error message in the title : Cannot deserialize the current JSON array (e.g. [1,2,3]). C#,

Comment: yeah, because you cannot deserialize json array to `KeyBoardRowBase`

Comment: It is now working with the fix from Salvin, thanks, I feel stupid not seeing this sooner

Comment: The json has `"rows": [[ ... ]]` which is array-of-array, there is no mapping to your model. What can you change (the easiest): the model or the json?

Comment: @lioleveau it's a good idea to serialize some test data from the C# model for testing, as it's very easy to mess up JSON encoding

Answer (score 1):

This should work:

**System.Text.json**

```
public class JsonTest
{
    [Fact]
    public void CanDeserialize()
    {
        var json = "[{\"rows\":[[\"A\",\"Z\",\"E\",\"R\",\"T\",\"Y\",\"U\",\"I\",\"O\",\"P\"],[\"Q\",\"S\",\"D\",\"F\",\"G\",\"H\",\"J\",\"K\",\"L\",\"M\"],[\"MAJ\",\"w\",\"X\",\"C\",\"V\",\"B\",\"N\",\"'\",\"DELETE\"],[\"123\",\",\",\"SPACE\",\".\"]]},{\"rows\":[[\"1\",\"2\",\"3\"],[\"4\",\"5\",\"6\"],[\"7\",\"8\",\"9\"],[\"ABC\",\",\",\"SPACE\",\".\"]]}]";

        var result = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<List<KeyboardSection>>(json);

        result.Count.ShouldBe(2);
        result[0].Rows.Count.ShouldBe(4);
        result[1].Rows.Count.ShouldBe(4);
    }
}

public class KeyboardSection
{
    [JsonPropertyName("rows")]
    public List<List<string>> Rows { get; set; }
}
```

**Newtonsoft**

```
public class JsonTest
{
    [Fact]
    public void CanDeserialize()
    {
        var json = "[{\"rows\":[[\"A\",\"Z\",\"E\",\"R\",\"T\",\"Y\",\"U\",\"I\",\"O\",\"P\"],[\"Q\",\"S\",\"D\",\"F\",\"G\",\"H\",\"J\",\"K\",\"L\",\"M\"],[\"MAJ\",\"w\",\"X\",\"C\",\"V\",\"B\",\"N\",\"'\",\"DELETE\"],[\"123\",\",\",\"SPACE\",\".\"]]},{\"rows\":[[\"1\",\"2\",\"3\"],[\"4\",\"5\",\"6\"],[\"7\",\"8\",\"9\"],[\"ABC\",\",\",\"SPACE\",\".\"]]}]";

        var result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<KeyboardSection>>(json);

        result!.Count.ShouldBe(2);
        result[0].Rows.Count.ShouldBe(4);
        result[1].Rows.Count.ShouldBe(4);
    }
}

public class KeyboardSection
{
    [JsonPropertyName("rows")]
    public List<List<string>> Rows { get; set; } = null!;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Changed the json from selvin comment and it worked